# Flutter concat two json response

Tags: json, flutter, dart, dio

I need to concat two json response (attach the second to the first)
because i have a model class which is a mix of fields from the first and second response.

My code:

```
List nextR = [];
final response = await dio.get(URL);
final result = response.data;
final response2 = await dio.get(URL);
final result2 = response2.data;
nextR.add(result);
```

i tried `nextR.join(...)` and `nextR.extend(...)` but it does not work

Now i receive this error (For Ezra solution)

```
Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 2)
E/flutter (26428): {example:.......
```

The first response is:

```
{
    "SData": {
        "series": "example",
        "Table": {
            "year": "2021",
            "Info": [
                {
                    "year": "2021",
                    "turn": "1",
                    "date": "2021-01-01",
                    "time": "23:00:00Z"
                },
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The second one is:

```
{
    "SData": {
        "series": "example",
        "Table": {
            "year": "2021",
            "Info": [
                {
                    "year": "2021",
                    "Results": [
                        {
                            "number": "18",
                            "ac": "none",
                            "Time": {
                                "time": "no time"
                            },
                        },
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I want to merge "Results" into the first response

Comment: This is happening because you've used `final` try using `var`

Comment: anirudh, I don't think that's what they're asking-- I think they want to add both result and result2 to the nextR List. If that's correct, then it has little to do with json.

Comment: @Ezra but the user has already stated `nextR.add(result);`

Comment: yes, I think they want to add both, so they need to add ```result2```? I could be wrong. @lukko, please clarify.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the other interpretation. @anirudh, is this what you think they meant?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to add them both to the list as separate entities:

```
nextR.add(result2);
```

If you want to merge them:

```
import 'dart:convert';
//...
final response = await dio.get(URL);
final result = response.data;
final response2 = await dio.get(URL);
final result2 = response2.data;
var data = jsonDecode(result)
data.addAll(jsonDecode(result2)
```

Comment: Yes, i want to merge them. 
it seems the right way, but now i receive the error posted above (I've updated the question)

Comment: Can you provide an example api response that dio gives?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Spread Operator`

```dart
const user1 = {
    name: 'Jen',
    age: 22,
};
  
const user2 = {
    name: "Andrew",
    location: "Philadelphia" 
};
  
const mergedUsers = {...user1, ...user2};

console.log(mergedUsers)
```

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question. I think dio returns strings, so OP needs to parse it to json first, and then combine. Either the spread operator or `.addAll` works for that